# Power source for Arduino uno, sparkfun usb shield and adafruit motor shield

Tags: arduino-uno, power, motor, shields, battery

I'm having trouble powering my boards altogether. Right now, I'm using 8x AA batteries to power everything. Running my arduino with one shield runs fine, but not with both shields stacked on top of my arduino. I've even tried powering it with an extra 4x AA batteries on my motor shield, but it still won't run. The way it's stacked is; arduino uno board, usb host shield then motor shield.

Comment: We don't know how your batteries are connected, or what power requirements your devices all have.

Comment: I have a 8xAA battery holder that's connected to the arduino uno via the 2.1mm plug and on my motor shield I have 2 DC motors and 2 servo motors that all require 6v. If that is what you mean by power requirements(?) If you mean power requirements for boards, I know that with the uno, it is suggested I use between 9v-12v, so I just went by the 12V.  @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Sounds odd. Do the lights on the boards turn on? Are the sparkfun and adafruit shields pin compatible? Sometimes shields by different companies use the same pins for transmitting data.

Comment: I can power a Mega, motor shield and a wifi shield connected to 2 motors, a servo and a variety of sensors using 4-5 AA batteries, so 8 should be more than adequate for your needs.

Comment: Yes, the lights on all boards are turned on. I've tried again with all boards stacked on top of each other and realised that the USB host shield works when I disconnect 2 servos from the motor shield. However, the DC motors from the motor shield still does not work. I'll look into the pins now. But if they do use the same pins for transmitting data, is there a solution for that? Thanks @bladepanthera

Comment: If that is the case, you might have to get clever with some rewiring of pins. I had to do that for my adafruit wifi shield as it uses the same pins as my arduino motor shield. Cross that bridge if it comes to it, though!

Comment: Can I ask, how did you find out that they used the same pins? @bladepanthera

Comment: Documentation for the boards. They usually clearly describe which pins are being used.

Comment: IF your motors are powered VIA the Arduino board "there will be problems". The motors should receive power directly from the battery on their own voltage input line. If the power goes via the SArduino board you have a good chance of noise problems AND if the Arduino voltage regiulator is used you will exceed its ratings for all except the tiniest of motors. As ever a circuit diagram is essentially mandatory. Words are often very ambiguous in situations like this. Your actual question gives no clues at all and your comments cannot be interpreted with certainty.

Comment: I've already tried powering the motor shield with it's own power source using 4xAA battery holder, while at the same time powering the arduino with 8xAA battery holder. But the motors still won't move when it's stacked on top of the usb host shield and arduino board. @RussellMcMahon

Comment: (1) Circuit diagram !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! please (2) When you say "still won't move" the meaning is potentially broad. ... when you do what? When what is connected how. Saying shields stacked on top of each other is about information free - that's what shields do. | You say "USB host shield" Which one? Web reference? Maker?  What happens i it is absent, if you know? If you don't know, why not? | What happens if you power the motor boaard stand alone and the assert the motor activating pins with a jumperto +5V or whatever is required ? If you have not done it you should do so and report back. ||

Comment: You say the motors do not move but, why should they? Have you chcked at the shield input that the signal that is meant to make them move is appearing at thje pin that you think it should ? This can be done with a meter oran LED and a resistor. etc. | At the moment from our viewpoint you are supplying semi random pieces of information with their relatrionshiop not obvious and gaaaps. You need to supply a coherent consistent complete picture if you want to maximise use of the available hive mind.

Comment: Did you check about pin compatibility? And what code are you using to run the motors? The standard example?

Comment: AA batteries are fine for small hobby motors - the issue is that you shouldn't be running the motors off the same regulator as the logic circuitry.  Ideally you would not run the motors off a regulator at all, but rather choose some suitable for the voltage of the pack itself.  You may however need to obtain a lower dropout regulator for the Arduino, or reduce it's operating voltage to 3.3v - the stock 5v regulator may start to drop out if the battery pack voltage dips below 7.something volts under load of the motors.

Answer (score -1):

Its a very bad idea to power everything from the same battery source. Most motors, especially ESP, generate large current spikes, rather than draw a small current throught. AA batteries are not designed for this.

You can get away with using AA batteries for micro-controllers, shields. However, keep motors on a sweater power supply. There are batteries for specific motor types, and these will typically have a high current rating. Of course, without a circuit diagram, I cannot go into details. I'll update my answer when you do.

Comment: It's not "a very bad idea" it merely requires some care - and a lower dropout regulator than stock wouldn't be a bad idea.  What is a problem is trying to run the motors off the logic regulator.